# Messaging system design - one queue per one message type vs. one queue for all messages

Tags: messaging

I want to implement a messaging system with following actors:

1) Web interface
2) Daemon
3) Database

The web interface sends requests to the daemon, which are placed in a queue (ActiveMQ).

The daemon reads the messages, processes them and writes some data into the database.

Both web interface and the daemon access the database.

If required, additional daemons may be connected to the queue (to improve performance).

---

There are 4 types of messages directed to the daemon. Plus, I want the daemon to send a "heartbeat" message in regular intervals so that I (or a monitoring app) knows whether a particular daemon is alive or not.

I can design the system in various ways:

1) Put all messages from the web interface to daemon in queue A, the heartbeat messages into queue B.

Queue A will contain messages of different types.

2) Put all messages of type 1 into queue A1, messages of type 2 into queue A2 etc.

In this case, every queue will contain messages of just one message type.

Both designs are technically possible.

My question: How can I decide, which of them is better?

What criteria need to be taken into consideration?

Thanks in advance

Dmitri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ordering of your messages is unimportant, or is handled appropriately by your app then of course having each message in a separate queue will allow for more robust scaling options. But at the expense of having to maintain 5 queues instead of 2. I'm not sure how much is that harder, but suspect not much once you get used to it.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "maintain the queue"?

Comment: administrative tasks, such as creating these queues, monitoring them, dealing with failed messages

Answer (score 1):

@Dmitri, if there is difference in volume of message of particular message type.. for e.g. if your message of type1 is expected to be 100 messages per minute where as type2 is expected to be 2 message per minute then, it would make sense to have separate queue due to following reasons:-

1. You can configure different concurrent message listeners based on
   load. for e.g in above case , you may want to configure 10 message
   listeners for type1 and only 1 message listener for type2.
2. It can happen if message of type2(though smaller in number) sits
   at very end of queue and need to wait for all type1 messages to be
   processed for their turn.